field indicating last modification of a documont in mongodb
I am building an API over my mongodb cluster. Each call for the API should return only the newest values or the values that have been modified seen the last call. I thought i need to add a field to each ducoment either representing the insertion timestamp or an auto incrementing field.
However, I am running in a highly distributed env.
I have many insertion pods the listen to a kafka topic and each is executing the following:
db.collection.bulk_write(operations)

Where operations is a list of ReplaceOne operations. Each containing the upsert=True key.
So i am afraid the if this new field is determined inside each pod, there might be concurrency issues.
Therefore, I am looking for this field to be generated inside my mongodb cluster. Is there any good way to do so?

You can also try using the ObjectId field type. What kind of MongoDB cluster is yours?

I am using the community version. can you explain a bit more how would ObjectId would help me?  mayby if I was only using insertion it would have worked. But I am using the replace one operation which means the _id wont change everytime I execute replace

_id is unique within a collection (acts as primary key). ObjectId is composed of timestamp + a random value generated once per process + incrementing counter; the link in my previous comment has more details. Optionally, you can also create a Unique Index on the new field - this will ensure of uniqueness, irrespective of the type.

You can also try $currentDate used with updates for a server-side date.

@prasad_ ObjectIds are usually generated in the driver on the client side, so they can not be sorted into creation order if more than one is created by different clients during the same second, and the time used to create the value will be the client-side clock, so there may be skew issues.

I have 1 more question as well. What will happened if I will insert a document without a _id field and 4 milliseconds after i will insert the seconds one. The first part of the ObjectId, which is the seconds since the Unix epoch should be the same. Than the second part is random so wouldn't the result of sorting them by _id will also be random?

You can try some such inserts/updates and see how it works in your environment with different data types as well. This has some related info: Where is the ObjectID _id generated?
